# Specific Gif Won't Restart in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a nutshell, I'm making a grid of icons that animate when you hover over them. It's pretty basic stuff, and works consistently across the browsers.

[Here's the page itself](http://willmurdoch.com/animTest/)

The js is as follows:

```js
$('.vidWrap img').hover(function(){
  mySrc = $(this).attr('src').split('_static')[0];
  $(this).attr('src',mySrc+'.gif');

},function(){
  $(this).attr('src',mySrc+'_static.gif');
});
```

But for some bizarre reason, in any version of IE, the animation of the pen will never restart. It goes to the end once, then stays there until I clear my cache. Every other icon works fine, so I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems seems to be with caching of the gif file. IE seems to cache it as an image somehow.

Try this JS instead:

```
var mySrc;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.vidWrap img').hover(function(){
        mySrc = $(this).attr('src').split('_static')[0];
        $(this).attr('src',mySrc+'.gif?' + Math.random());

    },function(){
        $(this).attr('src',mySrc+'_static.gif');
    });
});
```

The `Math.random()` adds a random number after the gif, making the browser think it's another file. The drawback with this is that the browser downloads this gif each time (the file is only 61.2 KB, so not that big of a deal).

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/95wyeyae/4/